# C++ Inheritance : Calling virtual method when it has been overridden

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, virtual-functions

I am trying to build a `service` object which can run (i.e. execute it's `run()` function) in a separate thread. This is the service object

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class service : public boost::noncopyable {
 public:
  service() : stop_(false), started_(false) { }

  virtual ~service() {
    stop();
    if (thread_.joinable()) {
      thread_.join();
    }
  }

  virtual void stop() { stop_ = true; }

  virtual void start() {
    if (started_.load() == false) {
      started_ = true;
      thread_ = std::thread([&] () {
        run();
      });
    }
  }

 protected:
  virtual void run() = 0;

  std::atomic<bool> stop_;

  std::atomic<bool> started_;

  std::thread thread_;
};
```

I am the creating a `test` class which inherits from this abstract class and is called in the `main()` function

```
class test : public service {
 public:
  test() : service() {
    std::cout<< "CTOR" << std::endl;
    start();
  }

  ~test() {
    std::cout<< "DTOR" << std::endl;
  }

 protected:
  void run() override {
    std::cout << "HELLO WORLD" <<std::endl;
  }
};


int main() {
  test test1;
  return 0;
}
```

Now when I execute this, why do I get an error saying `pure virtual function called`? The `run()` function is clearly overridden in the `test` class. Whats worse is that it runs correctly sometimes?

```
$ ./a.out
CTOR
DTOR
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception

$ ./a.out
CTOR
DTOR
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception

$ ./a.out
CTOR
DTOR
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception

$ ./a.out
CTOR
DTOR
HELLO WORLD

$ ./a.out
CTOR
DTOR
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: you are calling virtual function `start();`  in the constructor. That's the reason for this error.

Comment: @Jagannath That's perfectly well-defined here and is not an issue.

Comment: No, it's not. At this point, the derived object is already constructed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow along, step by step:

1) You construct the object.

2) You execute the following piece of code:

```
if (started_.load() == false) {
  started_ = true;
  thread_ = std::thread([&] () {
    run();
  });
}
```

The parent thread immediately returns to `main()` where it *immediately* exits and destroys your object.

Here's your bug:

- You are not guaranteed that the thread started in `start()` is going to reach the call to `run()`, above, before the parent thread terminates the process. Both the child thread, and the parent thread runs concurrently.

So, every once in a while, the parent thread will destroy the object before the child thread gets in gear, and calls `run`().

At this point, the object whose `run`() method gets invoked, is already destroyed.

Undefined behavior.

The assertion you're hitting, every once in a while, is one possible result of this undefined behavior.

Comment: Shouldnt the `thread_.join()` in the base class' destructor ensure that the object is not destroyed before the thread is run?

Comment: @subzero There are three steps here: (A) Derived class destructor (B) Thread body executed (C) Base class destructor. (A) definitely happens before (C). But nothing is preventing (A) happening before (B) before (C), which means the vtable is unwound before `run()` got called before `join()` got called.

Comment: @subzero `ensure that the object is not destroyed`  In MT programming, it's your job to have control over the object's lifetime.  Leaving it up to the compiler invariably gives problems like this.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! How do I fix this? I can put a `thread_.join()` in the derived class destructor. I would like to wrap all the thread handling business in the base class? Can that be done?

Comment: @subzero: put the `join` call in the `stop` routine rather than the destructor and  ensure that the `test` destructor calls `stop`.  Alternately, make `service::run` a noop virtual function rather than pure virtual.

Comment: There's not actually undefined behavior here, as the `service` object won't be destroyed until after `join` returns.  But the `test` object might be destroyed (turning the object back into a `service` object) prior to `run` being called, so you get the "pure virtual" called.

Comment: Making service::run() a noop is still undefined behavior. I'm not aware of any requirement that vtable updates are thread-safe. Besides, the child process can resolve the virtual function, followed by parent process destroying the most-derived class that implements the virtual function, followed by the child process invoking the virtual function in a class that's already destroyed.

Comment: @ChrisDodd So you think calling a pure virtual function is defined behaviour?